# How to fake a Wi-Fi or 3G connected event on Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, 3g, connectivity

The question is pretty clear. Can I fetch a fake event for of Wi-Fi or 3G connected. Even for rooted phones will do. Googled a lot but could not find any answers. But I believe that this is possible. As **[this app on play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.littlelan.ReverseTether.Paid)** does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I got my answer. All I need to have is a rooted phone with [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401) installed on my phone. With an app called [Hack Connectivity Service](http://hack-connectivity-service.android.informer.com/) we can fake a Wi-Fi or mobile data connected status to the system even if Wi-Fi is not connected.

Comment: Whoever upvotes this answer requires this for some evil purpose, I suppose. :D

Answer (score 3):

Try [Fake Wifi Connection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-fake-wifi-connection-t2800416) (uses [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/)). It'll make apps believe Wi-Fi is connected.

[Hack Connectivity](http://www.digitalmobile.in/community/threads/fake-wifi-to-play-games-with-wifi-requirement.8461/) (another Xposed module) didn't work for me so I wrote my own module instead.

Answer (score 0):

Android reverse Tethering let connect you from USB and install an app who permet created a fake wifi connected status from android.

Bonne chance!!